# How to monitor dd progress with pkill?

Tags: process, dd, signals, progress-information

To install an OS, the [official raspberry pi site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)  proposes to run

```
dd bs=4M if=myiso of=/dev/sdb
```

followed by

```
pkill -USR1 -n -x dd
```

In order to show the progress.

Executing this last command, I do not have any output.

Why do I have any output and how can I monitor `dd` with `pkill`?

PS: Text from [site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dd` command need to be run in the background (i.e. with an ending `&`) or in another window in order to be able to be monitored. As written, the `pkill` command is launched after `dd` has completed its job.

Otherwise, you might run `pgrep dd` to see if it is still running.

Answer (score 0):

The output is displayed only in the pts/tty when you launched
the command
for example
I'm on tty5

```
dd launched on tty5      
pkill launched on tty5
the ouput is on tty5
```

Now i'm on pts/4

```
dd launched on tty5      
pkill launched on pts/4
the ouput is still on tty5
```